# Excel 2016 Slicer - select all except 1

Tags: excel, excel-2013, excel-2016, slicers

I have a slicer that contains 340 filters.  I would like to exclude 1 item.   How can I do this without having to manually select the other 339?

I would like to be able to toggle between including all items ie switching the filter off completely and including all items except the item AB12345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think you can do what you want by using CTRL+click on the item you don't want to see.

[I deselected one item using CTRL+click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCFeE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Consider iterating through all [SlicerItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839561.aspx) of specific [SlicerCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822652.aspx) in VBA and conditionally set the specific item to be `.Selected` as `False` using `.Caption` property (assumed below as *AB12345*):

```vb
Sub SelectSpecificItem()

    Dim slcCache As SlicerCache
    Dim index As Integer

    Set slcCache = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("SlicerName")  ' OR USE SLICER INDEX NUMBER

    With slcCache

        For index = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count            
            If .SlicerItems(index).Caption = "AB12345" Then                    
                .SlicerItems(index).Selected = False
            Else
                .SlicerItems(index).Selected = True    
            End If
        Next index

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can eliminate `If` block with one line: `.SlicerItems(index).Selected = Not .SlicerItems(index).Caption = "AB12345"`